# Hbase SnapShot Issue

Tags: hbase, snapshot

I have taken the snapshot in the hbase-0.94. When I try to move to another hbase-0.94.8 pseudo distributed mode (command is mentioned below)

```
./hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.snapshot.ExportSnapshot -snapshot mission_snapshot -copy-to hdfs:///xx.xx.xx.246:9000/hbase/
```

I get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Incomplete HDFS URI, no host: hdfs:///xx.xx.xx.246:9000/hbase
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:85)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1386)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:66)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1404)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:254)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.snapshot.ExportSnapshot.run(ExportSnapshot.java:610)
```

I used the telnet command to check another machine is connecting through port and both way ping is also happening.

I'm struck with this issue. Help me to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

use this
./hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.snapshot.ExportSnapshot -snapshot mission_snapshot -copy-to hdfs://xx.xx.xx.246:8082/hbase/